# Post form serialized data with additional parameter through ajaxsetup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I am using $.ajax to submit a form, I want to add a key-value pair to the submission that are not part of the form input and it is common for all my forms.
So i planned to move common part to ajaxsetup.
I want receive these in Action as two parameters like ModelData, TokenKey 
My html code

```html
<form id="frm">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="AjaxPost(); return false;" />
</form>
```

My Java Script

```js
$(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ data: { 'TokenId': 'TokenId Value'} });
    });

    function AjaxPost() {
        var frm = $("#frm");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Index',
            type: 'POST',
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function () { }
        });
    }
```

This is not working! If i removed data in AjaxPost function TokenId is posting,
Otherwise its not.

Comment: As per the docs, Its sets default values for future Ajax requests. It will not add new `key` in `frm.serialize()` object I suppose..

Comment: May I know why you are not storing the key value pair in a hidden field so that it also gets submitted likewise with the other form fields?

Comment: The easiest way to do this add hidden field to your form with the name of TokenId and set required value to that

Comment: Actually TokenKey is not related to my model, It is forms html attribute value, I want to receive this as separate string parameter in action...

Comment: @Nishan Senevirathna, Since this is required for all my Create and  Edit forms, Finding for a generic approach...

Comment: `data: $(yourForm").serialize() + '&' + $.param({ 'TokenId': 'TokenId Value' }, true);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would be a good solution:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalData, xhr){
  if (options.data)
    options.data += "&TokenId=TokenValue";
});
```

this will affect all ajax calls. Check out the codepen [DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/d302691f39fdba2ea8ac0d4ea6d8d463)

Comment: in case if there is no data,
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalData, xhr){

    if (options.data)
      options.data += "&TokenId=TokenValue";
    else if(!options.data.length)
      options.data = "TokenId=TokenValue";
    
  });

Answer (score 1):

When you use the jQuery serialize() function, it simply turns your form into a string in the format a=1&b=2&c=3. So you can certainly apply this function to two forms and concatenate the result, with an & between them, and use the result in your ajax call. You'd want some checks to make sure neither string is empty when you do the concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post(url,{key:value,data:frm.serialize},function(){
//do somehting
})
```

i usually do this its simple and easy, and you can add as many `key:value` pairs you want...

Comment: is it possible through ajaxsetup?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a hidden field to your form with the name of TokenId and required value. Or you can modify data like below.

```
data : fir.serialize()+"&TokenId=TokenId+Value";
```

Note: You have to Encode your data before append like above